None type object has no attribute eglGetCurrentContext. Nix not adding or linking open gl files
So i am using direnv with devenv for python development. But it doesnt seem to link my opengl files. i also tried to add them as packages but nothing seems to work. if i am outside of my devenv directory everything works. which tells me it must be devenv no properly linking or added the open gl files
  packages = [ pkgs.git pkgs.glfw pkgs.glm pkgs.lua pkgs.mesa pkgs.libcxx pkgs.libGL];

  # https://devenv.sh/languages/
  # languages.rust.enable = true;
  languages.python = {
    enable = true;
    version = "3.12.7"; 
    venv.enable = true;
    venv.requirements = ./requirements.txt;
  };

the error happens on python when i try to import open gl

Since you're using Devenv, can you try to use languages.python.libraries? At a cursory glance this seems to be likely what you want. In Nix library linking is handled better when the packages are written in the correct places. I could provide you a standard pkgs.mkShell example instead, as I'm unfamiliar with Devenv, but I'm not sure if you want to migrate your workflow.
